# Anyway to further abbreviate this code?

Tags: c#

I had a property like this:

```
private DataSet dsFoo = null;
public DataSet Foo {
    get {
        if (dsFoo == null) {
             dsFoo = PopulateFoo();
        }
        return dsFoo;  
    }
}
```

Thanks to C# 6, I abbreviated it to :

```
private DataSet dsFoo = null;
public DataSet Foo => dsFoo ?? (dsFoo = PopulateFoo());
```

Is there anyway to further abbreviate this property so that the declaration of dsFoo is on the same like as the property declaration?  Or is this as far as it goes?

Comment: Yeah that one extraneous line of code is really a drag...

Comment: @DStanley OCD comes with the job description :)

Comment: My sarcasm aside - no, that's about as terse as it gets.

Comment: If it doesn't have to be exactly `DataSet`, you could do `public Lazy<DataSet> Foo { get; } = new Lazy<DataSet>(PopulateFoo);`

Comment: Well, if it makes any better, you could remove explicit `null` assignment as `DataSet` should already be `null` by default.

Comment: @DStanley For some, coding is not a job but an art. And striving for excellence should be applauded, not ridiculed. I find it beautiful. (Now, if it's on paid employer time, then the employer's got a saying. But I admire his academic curiosity. No progress has ever been made without "*hmm... can I do it differently...?*". Of course, not many of those *hmm*s have led to progress, but you see my point, right?

Comment: To answer your question you won't be able to do this in one line as the backing field is private.  The property itself is public.  Remember readability is most important, the new version you posted I believe is still very readable.

Comment: _"Is there anyway to further abbreviate this property"_ -- abbreviate in what way? Are you looking strictly for the fewest characters? Do you care at all whether the code is readable? Thread-safe? There seem to me to be a lot of possible answers (including "nope, that's as short as it gets"). Without a clearer question, it's not really possible to know exactly what answer _you_ are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to further abbreviate this property so that the declaration of dsFoo is on the same line as the property declaration?

Ultimately, you will need a backing field.  To reflect the semantics of a lazily-created value, you can use [`Lazy<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx) like so:

```
private Lazy<DataSet> foo = new Lazy<DataSet>(PopulateFoo);
public DataSet Foo => foo.Value;
```

As an academic (and not recommended) solution to replicating the above in a single statement, similar behavior can be attained in C# 6 with:

```
public LazyImplicit<DataSet> Foo { get; } = new LazyImplicit<DataSet>(PopulateFoo);
```

where `LazyImplicit` is defined as:

```
class LazyImplicit<T> : Lazy<T>
{
    public LazyImplicit(Func<T> valueFactory) : base(valueFactory) { }
    public static implicit operator T(LazyImplicit<T> obj) => obj.Value;
}
```

The implicit conversion from `LazyImplicit<T>` to `T` allows you to declare `DataSet n = YourClass.Foo` and simultaneously ensure that `PopulateFoo` is called only on demand and not more than once per instance.  However, the method signature will show the `Foo` returning `LazyImplicit<DataSet>` rather than `DataSet`, which is nonidiomatic and requires the caller to know that the implicit conversion exists.